# Inexplicable exception occurring because of include()

Tags: php, exception

I really have no idea what I did to cause this exception, but I have deduced that this problem is occurring only because I am including a PHP script. Here is the error it is throwing:

```
[Tue Jun 19 01:33:28 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare sql_connect() (previously declared in core.php:6) in core.php on line 9
```

Here is `sql_connect()`:

```
function sql_connect(){
    $a = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(json_encode(array("failure"=>"SQL CON FAILURE: ".mysql_error()))); // Line 6
    mysql_select_db("whoSync", $a);
    return $a;
} //Line 9
```

More background: `core.php` is not actually running any code, it merely defines functions. Now here is why it is weird: when I include `core.php` in `home.php` it throws that exception above. Including `core.php` in any other file will *not* result in an error.

I am really good with PHP, but I have no idea what is happening. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you able to tell which PHP version you're using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `include` to `include_once` or `require_once`.

The issue is that you are calling/including a file multiple times which contains a function. The fatal error is thrown to prevent the function from being defined twice.

**Explanation:**

By using the *_once, PHP will only include the specified file once during the execution of the script. PHP does not support Method overloading (outside of the class scope) due to it's dynamic nature. A language like Java supports Overloading/Overriding of methods.

Let's say you have a file called home.php, about.php and sidebar.php. All three files call another file, database.php, which has a function called dbhandler().

dbhandler() has already been defined. If home.php is called, and it references sidebar.php, then database.php will be called twice. Using include_once/require_once, will only include database.php if it has not yet been called.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It means that `core.php` is already loaded, for example, some other file includes it, and `home.php` include that file will cause this. To prevent this, you could use `include_once` or `require_once` to make sure a file is included only once. Or you could make sure to include a file just once.